# What is the difference between using while and if conditions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm currently building a reactive form in Angular in which the form fields are adjusted dinamically depending on the user input.
Example of function to create the form:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: this.formBuilder.control('', {nonNullable: true}),
    isOne: this.formBuilder.control({value: null, disabled: true}, {nonNullable: true}),
    type: this.formBuilder.control({value: null, disabled: true}),
    model: this.formBuilder.control({value: null, disabled: true}),
    city: this.formBuilder.control({value: null, disabled: true}),
})
```

Then I made subscriptions to the form values that should enable/disable/change inputs when a condition is met or not:

```
this.form.get('name').valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => {
    if (newValue !== '') {
        this.form.get('isOne').enable();
    } else {
        this.form.get('isOne').disable();
    }
    ...
}
```

Because I don't want `model` field to change other things before the user touches it, I added the condition in the function that checks whether the field is pristine or not before doing the logic.

```
this.form.get('type').valueChanges.subscribe(newValue => {
    while (this.form.get('type').pristine) { // if (this.form.get('type').pristine) {
        return;
    }
    if (newValue === 'house') {
       this.form.get('model').disable();
       this.form.get('city').enable();
    } else {
       this.form.get('model').enable();
       this.form.get('city').disable();
    }
});
```

In my logic it makes sense to use `while` here becasue `pristine` is a condition that will be met for a while until the user touches it. Therefore, it seems to improve code readability. However, `if` can also handle the logic here and it is used much more often than `while` in javaScript.
My question is what are the implications of using `while` here? Does it adversely affects performance? Is there an advantage in using `if` instead of `while`?

I made the form using `while` and I expect it to be functionally the same as `if`.

Comment: Is it an infinite loop? it's returning.

Comment: @BojanKogoj No, it's not an infinite loop. The loop contains an unconditional `return`. It will always stop after the first iteration. You can replace `while` with `if` and you'll get the same behavior.

Comment: Your logic is wrong. `while` and `if` yield the same behavior in this case, because the loop body contains an unconditional `return`, but using `while` instead of `if` will confuse many people. The loop can't repeat because of the `return`. It doesn't make sense to use a loop. I recommend to replace `while` with `if`.

Comment: _"Does it adversely affects performance?"_ No, `while` and `if` have the same performance in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting proposition.

We can test: https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-2dqj59?file=index.js
Dont know how trust is the test, but surprising while condition is a bit faster.

The execution flow will be the same. While-return and If, when compiled, may generate scopes from different sizes, but dont believe that will be that different, and about performance, i think it will be irrelevant.

But, i believe the point is about maintainability, if another developer check this code, will be expecting a loop execution code, and not just the return, it will looks wrong. So maybe, it will be necessary some commentary code explanning. But an if condition wont need any further explanation, because everyone is teached like that.

Comment: Testing is a great idea, but I can see that `if` will be faster than `while` sometimes as well. This makes me think your test is not precise enough to test this, or because the difference is really small. I also question whether it would be different in different borwsers.

Comment: Good points, maybe when compiled its almost the same.